# ember.js: how to abort transitions if target matches current path

Tags: ember.js, transition, ember-router

Is there a general way (i.e. in application-router) to abort transitions if the target (including dynamic ids) matches the current route?

I tried hooking into willTransition but the transition.params I found seem to contain the current ids and I have nothing to compare them to.

Comment: Just to be curious, why would one need this?

Comment: @mavilein: I have some state on my pages that leads to css animations and such. Due to the nature of this app, users will invoke the URL they are actually at - so by aborting I want to avoid resetting the animation state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` attribute of the transition will reference the current route's params, not the target. What you need is to look at the models provided to the transition via its `providedModels` attribute. Your code should look like this:

```
willTransition: function(transition) {
  if ((this.get('routeName') === transition.targetName) &&
      (this.get('currentModel') === transition.providedModels[transition.targetName])) {
    transition.abort();
    return;
  }

  // ... other code here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in my app and I think it does what you're looking for.  Basically you test the `job_id` in the params against the `model.id` of your controller.

```
App.JobRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      if (this.controller.get('model.id') == transition.params.job_id) {
        transition.abort();
      }
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Yip, that's what I tried, but (at least in my environment) the params hash of the transition contains the id-set where I currently am and not the one the transition is pointing to. I'll re-check to make sure this isn't caused by my setup.

Comment: I just double checked and I get the new info (where I'm transitioning to) in the params of `willTransition`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I'll comment if I find the reason for my params situation.